# Create controller with already included classes laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am working with Laravel framework and I want to include my common classes in the controller file while I am creating controller from `php artisan`. For now it creates controller like

```
<?php namespace ReaPro\Http\Controllers\Home;

use ReaPro\Http\Requests;
use ReaPro\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class HomeController extends Controller {}
```

I want to include my common classes like

```
   <?php namespace ReaPro\Http\Controllers\Home;

use ReaPro\Http\Requests;
use ReaPro\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use ReaPro\Model\Page;
use ReaPro\Helpers\Common;
class HomeController extends Controller {}
```

So how can I pre include my

`use ReaPro\Model\Page;
use ReaPro\Helpers\Common;` 
Classes somewhere so that these may come with each controller by default when I create controller with `php artisan` ?

Comment: You could extend the existing command, prepare modified separate template file and use that instead. But it won't be future-proof - if laravel's template file changes, generated controllers will be outdated. It's also quite an effort just to avoid pasting a few "uses"  manually.

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel `GeneratorCommand` class is quite easy to extend for your own needs. [Here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7f62d81acb2001faafb21a32544464ebfc92476c/src/Illuminate/Routing/Console/ControllerMakeCommand.php) is the `ControllerMakeCommand` which extends `GeneratorCommand`. The most important part is in the `getStub()` method, from here you can see that it returns either `controller.stub` or `controller.plain.stub` depending on the options. These stubs are [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/7f62d81acb2001faafb21a32544464ebfc92476c/src/Illuminate/Routing/Console/stubs).

In short:

1. Create your own command for generating controllers
2. Extend `Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand`
3. Implement your own command in the same way as `Illuminate\Routing\Console\ControllerMakeCommand`
4. Create your own stubs